# jQuery. js - Always Scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a script to a blackjack website, but when i enter on the website (http://btcblackjack.org) the website keep scrolling down and never stops.

I deleted the file "jQuery. js" and the scrolling stopped. But the website needs the jQuery. js to work properly.

Here is the jQuery. js file:

The jQuery. js file is the original one from jQuery. com

Version 2.1.4

Comment: Did you write the javascript in main.js? It's got to be somewhere in your application that the page content is being moved down. Look through your code for it.

Comment: The problem is where you change the `height` and `top` css of `.cj-table` and `.gamblingTable` in your `placeTables()` function in `main.js`. You have an interval that calls `placeTables()` every 100 milliseconds and there's (probably) a feedback cycle involving the use of `Math.max()` and your `margin()` functions in `placeTables()`.

Comment: And how can i fix it?

Answer (score -1):

You can search for the code modifying the div that keeps adding  by searching for the div's selector. i.e. $('.cj-table') probably

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: If you want to use StackOverflow, you'll have to use it by its rules. I have not set them, and I am not trolling either. I am just trying to make StackOverflow better. Surf around the website for a couple of days, and very quickly you will gain reputation enough to answer the questions. Don't take anything personal. Thanks.